# Bash - variable assignment in a pipeline

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to create a script that monitors for failed login attempts and passes the IP address of those attempts as a variable. But I am having a bit of trouble.

I have the below command which spits out the IP addresses as expected.

```
tail -10 /var/log/authlog | grep '403 Forbidden' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | sort | uniq | sort
```

But I am struggling with getting them to pass as a variable.

```
tail -10 /var/log/authlog | grep '403 Forbidden' | ip_addr=$(grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | sort | uniq | sort) 
echo "The following IPs have failed login '$ip_addr'"
```

I get this as output.

```
The following IPs have failed login ''
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

*Update:*

I still had no luck getting the output to pass as a variable, so I just decided to output it to a file.

```
tail -10 /var/log/authlog | grep '403 Forbidden' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | sort | uniq | sort >> iplist.txt
```

Comment: Cut your original command at each pipe, and see if the output is what you expect. E.g. `tail -10 /var/log/authlog`, then `tail -10 /var/log/authlog | grep '403 Forbidden'`, ... .

Comment: Be sure to use the `--line-buffered` option on both of your `grep`s. Without it, `grep` won't output anything until it gets a buffer full of matches, or sees EOF.

Comment: grep -i ssh /var/log/auth.log | grep -i accept | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f11 | sort -u

Comment: type "sudo lastb"

Answer (score 1):

Your variable assignment using command substitution in the pipeline is actually working, but in a subshell rather than the current running shell ... That's [how a pipeline works in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) (*i.e. Each command in a multi-command pipeline, where pipes are created, is executed in its own subshell, which is a separate process*) ... Therefor, when the subshell for that part of the pipeline dies, the variable assigned will die with it as well ... Please, compare the following two situations:

```bash
$ echo "line1 word1 word2" | var="$(grep -o word1)"; echo "${var:-empty}"
empty
$
$ echo "line1 word1 word2" | (var="$(grep -o word1)"; echo "${var:-empty}")
word1
```

Fortunately, Bash has a shell option [`lastpipe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) which:

> If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last command
> of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell
> environment.

[Job Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html) is deactivated by default for non-interactive Bash shells i.e. the kind that your executable script file is run in with e.g. `./scriptfile` ... But, you can deactivate it even in interactive Bash shells with [`set +m`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) ... Please, compare the following two situations:

```bash
$ (echo "line1 word1 word2" | var="$(grep -o word1)"; echo "${var:-empty}")
empty
$
$ (shopt -s lastpipe; echo "line1 word1 word2" | var="$(grep -o word1)"; echo "${var:-empty}")
word1
```

Therefore, you can add `shopt -s lastpipe` to the top of your script file before the pipe-lined commands to enable that behavior.

Comment: I just learned something. Thank you. :) Now is there an advantage (or disadvantage) to using `shopt -s lastpipe` over what I suggested as an answer?

Comment: You're welcome @mpboden ... It's an honor for me :-) ... In your suggested solution, the assignment happens after the pipeline closes while with `lastpipe`, the assignment happens while it's open ... Other than that the end result is basically the same AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Once you enable the logging by `sudo touch /etc/{w,b}tmp`, the `sudo lastb` command will show an up-to-date list of bad logins.

You could also learn from the `fail2ban` package. `fail2ban(1) a set of server and client programs to limit brute force authentication attempts.`. Install it and read the documentationn, and the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Change your command around so that the variable is at the beginning instead of in the middle. Such as the following:

```
ip_addr=$(tail -10 /var/log/authlog | grep '403 Forbidden' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | sort | uniq | sort)
```